# req.getAttribute returning null

Tags: java, jsp

In servlet i have written

```
Map<String, Integer> amounts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
if(req.getParameter("from").equals("details")){


    employeeInformation.put("employeeName", retrievedUserInfo.getName());

    employeeInformation.put("employeeDepartment", retrievedUserInfo.getDepartment());
    employeeInformation.put("employeeDesignation", retrievedUserInfo.getDesignation());
    req.setAttribute("total", amounts.get("DayCareAmount"));

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(employeeInformation);
    System.out.println("Servlet json from user details" + jsonString);
    PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
    writer.write(jsonString);

    }
```

and in javascript i have written

```
<form action="./ssoServlet?from=amount" method="post">
<% String amount =  (String) request.getAttribute("total");%>
Total amount claimed 
 <input type="text" name="total" id="total" value = <%=amount %>  > 
</form>
```

However, in total amount claimed textfield null is displayed. If req.setAttribute and getAttribute doesnt work can i write two jsonStrings? How should i retrieve it in js?

My js function which retrieves data is:

```
function fetchDetails(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        // alert("s");
        //alert(xhttp.status); 
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {

            var JSONobj = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
             document.getElementById("name").value = JSONobj.employeeName ;
             document.getElementById("department").value = JSONobj.employeeDepartment ;
             document.getElementById("designation").value = JSONobj.employeeDesignation ;

        }
      };
    xhttp.open("POST", "./ssoServlet?from=details", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
```

Comment: No, that's not Javascript. Your second snippet is a `.jsp` file containing **Java** code.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt.. Yes

Comment: How are you dispatching the request from the servlet to the jsp ? Show the code where you do that.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: I don't see the code that forwards (or includes) the request to the JSP. You do that either with a `RequestDispatcher` or your web framework handles that, but I don't see evidence of either. Are you sure you're not just going to your jsp directly with your browser, rather than through the servlet?

Comment: Yes!I agree that i havent written dispatcher. But if i write dispatcher to direct to jsp then i feel it will affect my other parameters like employee name etc

Comment: I'm not really sure how you would otherwise provide the request parameter to the jsp, without Dispatching. It looks like you're combining a lot of functions in one servlet - you may want to separate servlets by logical grouping or by output type (one for json, one for dispatching to jsp) or by both.

Comment: Can u please suggest if i can create two json strings here?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't put anything in request attribute `total`:

```
Map<String, Integer> amounts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
// amounts Map is empty, so amounts.get("DayCareAmount") will return null
req.setAttribute("total", amounts.get("DayCareAmount"));
```

To make sure that everything is working right, first make your code simpler so there are fewer things that could be wrong:

```
req.setAttribute("total", 42);
```

Now check if the 42 shows up in your web page. If so, you can go back to your snippet:

```
Map<String, Integer> amounts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
amounts.put("DayCareAmount", 42);
req.setAttribute("total", amounts.get("DayCareAmount"));
```

Comment: I have 1 function which puts value in map

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load the JSP file before going through the servlet, so the parameter is never received by the JSP page.

Remember that form page does not reload after the ajax call, so you need to use the `RequestDispatcher` to  pass on the parameter.